# MATLAB add path temporarily

Tags: matlab

I'm working on a project containing some subprojects. Each subproject is located in a own folder.

```
projDir/subProj1
       /subProj2
```

and so on. Each subproject is a standalone running project. But now I want to use some functions of i.e. `subProj1` in `subProj2`. But the functions in `subProj1` should not be visible in general. So it is no good idea, to add the `subProj1`-path to the MATLAB-Path generally. Hence, I want to add this path in my .m-file stored in `subProj2` and after finishing this script, the path should be removed (automatically) by it's own. Is there any possibility, to add a path temporarily to the MATLAB-path variable?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`addpath`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/addpath.html?refresh=true) function only adds the files/folder to your path for the current Matlab session, assuming you don't call `savepath`. You also might find the `genpath` function helpful if you want to add subfolders.

Comment: aha, ok thank you. I thought `addpath` will add the path permanently. I will try it...

Comment: @paul_schaefer I thought exactly the same thing. I think I even wrote to the Mathworks to ask them to clarify this in the documentation. Maybe you can do the same?

Comment: ok, that works. Thanks a lot.

Interesting, because in the documentation they explicitly point, that a call of `addpath` within a function persists, even if the function is leaved. On the other hand, they suggest to use this in a startup script to modify the path after starting MATLAB....

Comment: However changes made to the path, even if not saved, may effect the execution of other functions called later in the same session (as pointed out in documentation)-which may not be desireable. Changes to the path that only have within-function scope would be nice, without the crud of creating termporary local pathdef files.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `path(path_to_add,path)` to add a path to the current path variable. Unless you do `savepath` you won't affect the global path.

I would do `path(strcat(pwd,'\subProj1',path)` etc. in the config .m script you have.